# Class android.support.v4.widget.Space is not found

Tags: android, github, android-studio, android-support-library

I cloned a project from a github repository to my personal computer which is using class `android.support.v4.widget.Space` and i'm trying to run it but it always gives me the same error:

```
Error:(6, 33) error: cannot find symbol class Space
```

In my gradle.build i have the following dependencies:

```
compile files('libs/pinit-sdk-1.0.jar')
compile project(':bounceScroller')
compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.2.1@aar'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+'
compile 'com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.6-2'
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.5.3'
compile 'com.github.pedrovgs:draggablepanel:1.8'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:utils-v4:1.2.1@aar'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
compile project(':rangeseekbar')
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'
compile project(':blurry')
```

I tried searching google and found that class `Space` exits in the android support library, does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your `support-v4` dependency from 21.0.3 to 22.1.0, because it was added in that version.

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html#revisions

Comment: I edited my dependencies to be like this:

compile files('libs/pinit-sdk-1.0.jar')
    compile project(':bounceScroller')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0'
    ....etc

but now i'm getting this error:

Error:Failed to find: com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0